# About C# combo combo

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, combobox

I have created a database in SQL Server 2008.
In one table (`customer`) I created the following columns:

> custid
>   custname
>   custadd
>   tpno

And another table named `payments`:

> paymentid
>   paymentdate
>   custname
>   description
>   chqno
>   duedate
>   accname
>   amount

I created a form for `customer` table. Data updating and its working.
In my second form I created a combo box for `custname` and after debugging combo box show all names in `customer` table. If I select on value and save the selected value is not updating in `payments` table. I need help for this problem.

Comment: What code do you have already? That would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Is the data of change being recorded into the database? 
Or isit just not being able to display the latest changes?

If it is the first you might want to put a SelectedIndexChanged on your combobox and update your database accordingly with the event. 
Also ensure to refresh your table so that it shows the updated value.

```
private void YourComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Collect Data from Combobox, 
    //Write it into your database
    //RefreshTable();
}
```

You can check this out: 
[MSDN: ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you could edit your question and put some codes it would help clear the picture

Comment: i need a sample code I am new to c# can anyone help. Data is not recorded in the database